# Schedule queue job doesn't work for me. I can't find any solution

Tags: php, laravel, scheduling

My code is as follows;

```
 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule){
   $schedule->job(new SendFeedbackEmail)->everyMinute();
 }
```

Comment: Why does it not work for you?

Comment: Have you created the CRON job?

Comment: @PowerStat I have tried but did not get any response.

Comment: @ColinMD  you mean app/console/commands

Comment: Can you add the SendFeedbackEmail Model

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a CRON job to run scheduler every minute.

The CRON will then automatically fire every minute and run whatever command you set in the kernel->schedule function.

You can find the details in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#introduction) under Starting The Scheduler

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup CRON job for this.

Can you run the following command to run this queue manually ?

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

Comment: Then it seems, you have some issues in SendFeedbackEmail class

Comment: $ php artisan schedule:run
Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php7.2' 'artisan' registered:users > '/dev/null' 2>&1
Running scheduled command: App\Jobs\SendFeedbackEmail

Comment: Running scheduled command: App\Jobs\SendFeedbackEmail
----I have a output command